# scrapy pipeline process_item not working (yet another not working)

Tags: python, scrapy

item not working question . but i have tried my very best on doing research, still i have to raise a questions. i have simplified the code as below.

to make it short, i want to get the details of some products from a web site, i have to use splash to make myself able to read some css. I have registered an item and two db classes, my plan was to store products in product table and their image paths in another .

However, at the end the images were downloaded but the item pipeline has not been triggered.

in my pipeline, i can only obtain two prints, -->

- pipeline inited:
- end init

Though i can get the picture but i cannot get my message

> print( "pipeline" + image_url)

most importantly

```
pipeline.py
=============
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from itembot.database.models import Products, db_connect, create_products_table
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

class ImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item["image_urls"]:
             print("pipeline" + image_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x["path"] for ok, x in results if ok]
        print("imagepath" + image_paths)
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item["image_paths"] = image_paths
        return item


class ItembotPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):

        print("pipeline inited: " )
        engine = db_connect()
        create_products_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        print("end init")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print("pipeline Entered : ",item )

        print("pipeline Entered : item is products ",item )
        products = Products(**item)
        try:
            session = self.Session()
            print("pipeline adding : ",item )
            session.add(products)
            session.commit()
            print("pipeline commited : ",item )
            session.refresh(products)
            item[id] = products[id]
            yield item[id]
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
        session.close()
        if(products[id] is not None):
        print("pipeline 2if: ",item )
        productsphotos = ProductsPhotos(**item)
        try:
        session = self.Session()
        session.add(productsphotos)
        session.commit()
        session.refresh(productsphotos)
        except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
        finally:
        session.close()
        return item
```

and most most importantly, the spider

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
    from scrapy import Request
    from w3lib.html import remove_tags
    import re
    from ..database.models import Products
    from itembot.items import ItembotItem
    from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

    class FreeitemSpider(scrapy.Spider):
                name = "freeitem"

        start_urls = [
        "https://google.com.hk" ,
        ]
        def parse(self, response):
        yield SplashRequest(url=response.url, callback=self.parse_product, args={"wait": 0.5})

        def parse_product(self, response):
        products = response.css(" div.classified-body.listitem.classified-summary")

        c = 0
        item = []
        for product in products:
            item = ItembotItem()
            imageurl = {}
            fullurls=[]
            item["title"]= product.css("h4.R a::text").extract_first()

            pc = product.css("div#gallery"+str(c) + " ul a::attr(href)").extract()
            for link in pc:
                 fullurls.append(response.urljoin(link))
            item["image_urls"]= fullurls
            url = product.css("a.button-tiny-short.R::attr(href)").extract_first()
            item["webURL"]= response.urljoin(url)
            c = c+1

            yield [item]
```

here is my item.py

```
import scrapy
class ItembotItem(scrapy.Item):
    id = scrapy.Field(default"null")
    title = scrapy.Field(default="null")
    details = scrapy.Field(default="null")
    webURL = scrapy.Field(default="null")
    images = scrapy.Field(default="null")
    image_urls = scrapy.Field(default="null")


class ProductsPhotos(DeclarativeBase):
__tablename__ = "products_photos"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_ID = Column(ForeignKey(Products.id),nullable=False)
    photo_path = Column(String(200))

    parent = relationship(Products, load_on_pending=True)
```

settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
"itembot.pipelines.ItembotPipeline": 300,
"scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline": 1,
}
IMAGES_STORE = "./photo"
```

model.py

```
class Products(DeclarativeBase):
__tablename__ = "products"
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
title = Column(String(300))

webURL = Column(String(200))
def __str__(self):
return self.title

class ProductsPhotos(DeclarativeBase):
__tablename__ = "products_photos"
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
product_ID = Column(ForeignKey(Products.id),nullable=False)
photo_path = Column(String(200))

parent = relationship(Products, load_on_pending=True)
```

Comment: use button `{}` to correctlu format code. now you have wrong indentions and it looks like you have `yield [item]` outside `for product` loop.

Comment: thanks! i just correct that here, i didnt mean to have that error in my code. thanks..

Answer (score 3):

I see one big mistake which can explain your problem.

First

```
class ImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline)
```

Don't use the same name for own class as for parent class

Better do

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline)
```

And now your main mistake

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   ...
   "scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline": 1,
}
```

You use standard `ImagesPipeline` from `scrapy.pipelines.images`,
not your `ImagesPipeline` (`MyImagesPipeline`) from `itembot.pipelines`

So it downloads images but it doesn't run `print("pipeline" + image_url)`

It should be

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    ...
    "itembot.pipelines.ImagesPipeline": 1,
}
```

or if you use name `MyImagesPipeline`

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    ...
    "itembot.pipelines.MyImagesPipeline": 1,
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I start to get more error messages but at least i know i am in my pipeline. so, my next issue is to find out why the other pipeline didnt fire... thanks!

Comment: however, i got my printout in the get_media_requests but not in item_completed.. i basically used provided codes

Comment: class FImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

 def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    print("at pipeline")
    for image_url in item['image_urls']:
     yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

 def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
    image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
    if not image_paths:
      raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
    item['image_localpaths'] = image_paths
    print("pipeline")
    yield(item)